# If we put series into the exponent of e, do they have the same result in the exponent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If we have an infinite Series $S$ that converges into a number $N$, does that also apply for $e^S = e^N$?

I saw an example for $S=1 + \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{8} + \ldots = 2$, which makes sense and to take both sides as an exponent for a specific number still makes perfect sense.

But is this true for all series?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What does $e^S$ mean when $S$ is a series?

Comment: As the exponential map is continuous, the exponential of the limit is indeed equal to the limit of the exponential. This is true for any continuous map.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's some confusion about exactly what you're asking in the comments; at least one comment seems to be answering a different question.

First, the question that you actually asked is completely trivial (so trivial that one wonders whether you meant something else.) Say $$S=1+\frac12+\frac14+\dots .$$The equal sign says that the two sides are exactly the same thing, so yes of course $$s^S=e^{1+\frac12+\dots};$$there's nothing to prove here, the two expressions are simply synonymous.

A different, slightly less trivial and definitely more interesting question:

> > Say $S_n=1+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{2^n}$, so $S_n\to2$ as $n\to\infty$. Does it follow that $e^{S_n}\to e^2$?

As pointed out in a comment, the answer to that is also yes, since the exponential is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k$ is a convergent series, then let $s_n:= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k$ for $n \in \mathbb N.$

If $ s_n \to N$ as $ n \to \infty$, then

$$e^{s_n} \to e^N$$

as $ n \to \infty$, since the exponential function is continuous.